# i want to save op=R and s=5, but my code show garbage output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int N,i,s;
    char op;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int a[N];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    scanf("%c %d",&op,&s);
    printf("%c %d",op,s);
}
```

If i include this `for` loop in my code and then execute this code, `scanf` doesn't read my input.
If i insert value of opand s is R and 5 then the output is garbage.

And if remove the `for` loop, then i `printf` print the correct answer.

Comment: What's your exact input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consume the trailing `\n` character. The easiest way to do it is to write:

```
scanf(" %c %d",&op,&s);  //notice the space before %c
```

Comment: Depends what version of C you're using.  C99 supports it.  Many compilers support it as an extension in C89 as well.

Comment: But still it should work @Igor? It works perfectly on my compiler! :-D

Comment: Of course, it's still a very bad idea to create a VLA with a user-controlled (read: attacker-controlled) size.

Comment: May I ask which *standard C* do you mean. (I'm sorry if that sentence seems a bit sarcastics - it isn't meant to be.)

Comment: The `%c` format specifier is one of the rare exceptions (`%[` is the other) to `scanf()`'s normal skipping of leading white space.